# create-react-app: command not found after installation

Tags: bash, macos, create-react-app

I've installed create-react-app using this command:

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

but when I run:

```
   create-react-app my-app
```

I get this:

```
-bash: create-react-app: command not found
```

I'm using OSX so I've updated the `.bash_profile` to this as instructed after installing node

```
export PATH=$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH
```

It's frustrating because it works perfectly fine on my other Mac and I've read countless forums trying to troubleshoot the issue. Can anyone shed some light on this issue for me without being rude?

Comment: Did you create a new shell after adding the line with the `export`?

Comment: what is path seen when you do `which create-react-app`?

Comment: @Inian `which create-react-app` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add this to my `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/rafaelheard/.npm-packages/bin
```

then restart the Terminal